# Why is there no common "docking" interface for express rack payloads?

Tags: iss, crewed-spaceflight, payload

It seems strange to me that given all of the concerns about living space and color palette aboard ISS, the data/power/cooling ports for different mid-deck locker equivalent (MLE) express rack payloads are on the fronts of the lockers.

Why not have some kind of snap-in docking connector which includes all the necessary power, data, air, water, gas, and vacuum connections? This could go on the back of the locker instead of the front, and would therefore be out of the way of the astronauts.

Yes, it would mean the lockers would lose a tiny bit of interior space, since the locker design would now have to accommodate a pre-ordained set of connectors in a certain arrangement. But MLEs are already almost totally arbitrary anyway.

And yes — I realize that not all payloads use all the connectors — but that doesn't necessarily matter. One could simply have dead ends in the MLE for these, or even not connect those particular pipes to the dock.

Is it mostly historical, or is there a good reason locker connections are done the way they are?

Comment: Links to a couple of pictures would be nice.

Comment: Might it have something to do with the requirement for the Express racks to be compatible with ARIS? https://web.archive.org/web/20090717221852/https://mistprod.hosc.msfc.nasa.gov/E-basicaccomodations/E3.html

Comment: It’s probably something to do with quick access and visibility for safety reasons. If the ports were on the side/back of the rack, it would be harder to spot leaks / disconnections and fix them.

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is that there are other components behind the payload volume in an EXPRESS Rack that would interfere with running all those connections through the back. The AAA (Avionics Air Assembly), the RIC (Rack Interface Controller), and the SSPCM (Solid State Power Control Module) all take up quite a bit of space.

[image]

([Image Source](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20140010107/downloads/20140010107.pdf))

Plus, all the air cooling provided by the AAA is already ducted through the rear of each locker location. Each payload can reject up to 150W in heat this way, with anything more requiring MTL (Moderate Temperature Loop) water cooling. The AAA fan also routes all return air through the rack smoke detector, a critical safety measure.

[image]

At the bottom of the rack where there's room, the EXPRESS Rack does have two ISIS (International Subrack Interface
Standard) drawers with blind mate power and data connectors.

[image]

ESA also investigated moving more connectors in their EDR (European Drawer Rack) to blind mate versions, but ran into space constraints:

> During the EDR design phase, considerable effort has been made to
> maximise the number of standard containers (lockers and drawers)
> available to payloads. Simple payload exchange also requires that
> payloads be installed and removed by front access to the rack. This
> necessitated the accommodation of EDR carrier subsystems in the back
> of the rack, which in turn led to very crowded arrangements with
> serious difficulties in servicing and repair. Some design constraints
> and access requirements of standard equipment to be used by EDR turned
> out to be incompatible with the access constraints imposed by a tilted
> rack, so that finally **one payload drawer ‘slot’ on the front of the
> rack had to be allocated to EDR subsystems**. The very limited space
> available for EDR subsystems and the constraints imposed by the
> standardised support equipment made it necessary to optimise the
> allocation of resources to payloads. **It turned out to be impossible to
> route all available resources to all payload slots in parallel. Safety
> constraints also had to be respected. The actual routing of cabling
> and piping to payloads itself turned out to be a major design
> constraint.** While ISIS drawers allow most electrical connections to be
> routed through self-mating connectors at the back of the drawer, the
> operating concept for ISS lockers necessitates that all resources
> except air cooling be connected to the front of the locker. This leads
> to a very large number of connectors – electrical, water, gas and
> vacuum – being on the front of the rack. Consequently, the assessment
> of resource distribution to EDR payloads is still on-going.

([Source](https://www.esa.int/esapub/bulletin/bullet108/chapter13_bul108.pdf))

There's also the utilization aspect of it that makes plumbing water and vacuum to each rack impractical and a waste of resources/space. The EXPRESS Rack only has enough MTL flow to support two payloads simultaneously, so there's no need for more than two MTL connectors in the rack. **And only ONE payload or system is allowed to use the VES (Vacuum Exhaust System) at a time on the entire ISS.** This is to avoid cross contamination of payloads, and to prevent unanticipated chemical reactions between two experiment byproducts within the VES. It would a huge waste of space to have 64 available connections to it onboard, when very few payloads actually use it as a resource.

The PRO (Payload Rack Officer) is responsible for controlling payload VES usage by opening/closing the rack vacuum vent valve. That way NASA can manage and verify VES users, instead of letting Payload Developers open/close their internal payload vacuum valves at will. I was an [OC (Operations Controller)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payload_Operations_and_Integration_Center#Operations_Controller_(OC)) at MSFC, and was responsible for ensuring all payloads resource usage was in compliance with the applicable Flight Rules and Payload Regulations. Unless the EXPRESS Racks had eight vacuum valves, it would be impossible to ensure only one user at a time if there were eight different connection points per rack.

Finally, and probably most importantly, there's the safety aspect of it. A blind mate vacuum connector (a literal hole in ISS) is not a great idea. And adding EIGHT of them per rack is an even worse idea. Same with water and nitrogen - you don't want either of those leaking within a rack which will make it hard to locate the source of a leak.